# Why won't this column split into two columns with tidyverse?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame with one column, `data`. A sample:

```
data
13.43,100.34
12.344,98.3242
```

I want to separate the numbers either side of the comma into two columns (and delete the comma), 'A' and 'B'. I.e. the objective is:

```
A       B
13.43   100.34 
12.344  98.3242
```

I've tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)

new_df <- old_df %>% separate(data, into = c('A', 'B'), sep = '^.+,')
```

but printing the `new_df` shows a blank `A` column:

```
A       B
        100.34 
        98.3242
```

Does anybody know why/how to fix?

Comment: Don't you just need `new_df  <- old_df %>% separate(data, into = c('A', 'B'), sep = ',')` ?

Comment: @RonakShah that did the trick, thanks!